# what is the exchange rate Expectation? I am confused about it

Tags: exchange-rate

Suppose now the rate of EUR/USD is 1. and in half-year, maybe become 1.25EUR/USD, or 0.8 EUR/USD, the probability of each case is 0.5.
what's the Expectation of EUR/USD in half-year? And, what's the Expectation of USD/EUR in half-year?
answer 1:

```
E(EUR/USD) = 0.5*1.25 + 0.5*0.8 = 1.025 EUR/USD。
```

answer 2: since 1.25EUR/USD is equivalent to 0.8 USD/EUR , and 0.8EUR/USD is equivalent to 1.25 USD/EUR, so

```
E(USD/EUR) = 0.5*1.25 + 0.5*0.8 = 1.025 USD/EUR。
```

Both USD and EUR ate expected to be appreciated. It's confusing me.

Comment: In general, forgetting FX, do we expect E(1/X) to equal 1/E(X)? For example, if X can be 1 or 2 with the same probability 1/2, then E(1/X) = (1+1/2)/2 = 3/4 ;  But E(X) = (1 + 2)/2 = 3/2 and 1/E(X) = 2/3.

Comment: Yes concavity leads to some counterintuitive results for FX rates, see also here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siegel%27s_paradox#:~:text=Siegel's%20paradox%20is%20the%20phenomenon,consumption%20goods%20after%20prices%20become. Your result vanishes when using log-exchange rates though.

Comment: If random variable X is strictly positive non-constant, and E(X) is non-zero, the function f(x)=1/x is strictly convex, by [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) 1/E(X) is strictly less than E(1/X).

Comment: Thanks I meant convexity. Why many find these cases puzzling is that here it looks like both Americans and Europeans could gain by swapping currencies (assuming risk neutrality). At least on the surface it seems like they are creating value from nothing.